# How to change the way solr assigns relevance score to documents?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet, solr4

I am trying to search in Solr Instance with :

```
\\123.45.67.89\Lists\PLAYLIST\EAST
```

and it would return me results like:

```
Some Text: \\123.45.67.89\Lists\SAVELIST\ATTTA
Some Text: \\123.45.67.89\lists\PLAYLIST\ABC
Some Text: \\172.21.52.41\Lists\PLAYLIST\EAST
```

I am sorting based on relevant score and `ID` field.

It seems that instead of returning exact matches first, Solr somehow splits everything in search term and then returns those which has the highest score for each term. I am using `Text_general` filed type. I am sending query through SolrNet like:

```
SolrQueryByField query = new SolrQueryByField("body", @"\\123.45.67.89\Lists\PLAYLIST\EAST");
solrQuery = solr.Query(query, new QueryOptions
{
    Rows = 100,
    Start = 0,
    OrderBy = new[] {new SortOrder("ID", Order.DESC), new SortOrder("score", Order.DESC) },

});
```

If I swap the sort order with relevance first and then ID second then it just ignores the latest records existing in the solr instance and would return older records (2-3 days old) instead of latest records with the same text. *(ID is auto increment number and shows latest records in order by desc)*

My field has different types of text ranging from XML, to text and some containing URL an file paths etc.

**My Question:**

Is there a way to modify Solr scoring method, so that exact matches are scored higher than frequency of each search terms splitted on `\` or `.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to found the way to get relevant results. I need to [Boost](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ) the query. I did:

```
SolrQueryByField query = new SolrQueryByField("body", @"\\123.45.67.89\Lists\PLAYLIST\EAST");
query.Boost(100);
```

and that resulted in exact matches being returned first.

Comment: note: you can't boost scores lower or negatively (AFAIK); you must raise up all other scores instead

Answer (score 0):

try indexing the specific field with the following analyzer:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory
text_general is not good for file paths

Comment: I can't really use that, I have so much other data in different records, there are only few records with file path and I am having problem with them